# How to write if-then-else regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

The following code is a regex for finding substring from a dataframe.

How to modify the regex as follows:

```
if x[0] is an English letter, that is, [a-zA-Z], then keep the first `\b`, else remove it
AND
if x[-1] is an English letter, that is, [a-zA-Z], then keep the last `\b`, else remove it

for k, v in keyword.items():
        pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in v)
        df[str(k)] = df['string'].str.contains(pat).astype(int)

String = 'BEAUTY Company is good, 歡迎~~YOU, SALE'
BEA: not match
Com: not match
歡迎: match
SALE: match
```

Thank you.

Comment: It is an XY problem, I bet you just want `pat = r'(?<!\w)(?:{})(?!\w)'.format("|".join([re.escape(x) for x in v]))`

Comment: No, it's not what I need. If the first character of the keyword is an English character, then the character before it in  the string, called `t`, must not be an English character. If otherwise, for example, a Chinese character, then `t` can be any characters.

Comment: Then, [`pat = r'(?!(?<=[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z])(?:{})(?<![A-Za-z](?=[A-Za-z]))'.format("|".join([re.escape(x) for x in v]))`](https://regex101.com/r/dEYAE1/2)? Is it Python 3?

Comment: Yes, Python 3.  Can we use (?(?=regex)then|else)?

Comment: You do not need `(?(?=regex)then|else)`. You can, but what for? Try what I suggest.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you, Wiktor.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew smells like an answer to me... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
pat = r'(?!(?<=[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z])(?:{})(?<![A-Za-z](?=[A-Za-z]))'.format("|".join([re.escape(x) for x in v]))
```

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dEYAE1/2/).

The main thing here is the lookarounds, `(?!(?<=[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z])` and `(?<![A-Za-z](?=[A-Za-z]))`.

The `(?!(?<=[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z])` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location (i.e. the first char of the keyword) is an ASCII letter that is preceded with another ASCII letter (checked with the positive lookbehind `(?<=[A-Za-z])`).

The `(?<![A-Za-z](?=[A-Za-z]))` is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location (i.e. the last char of the keyword) is an ASCII letter that is followed with another ASCII letter (checked with the positive lookahead `(?=[A-Za-z])`).

Note that you do not have to add these lookarounds to each alternative in the regex, just use them to enclose a `(?:...|...)` like alternation group that you may build dynamically as I have shown above.

Also, `[re.escape(x) for x in v]` is handy if any of the keywords can contain special regex chars that should be treated as literal chars.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Qwc7h1):

```
import re
s = 'BEAUTY Company is good, 歡迎~~YOU, SALE'
v = ['BEA','Com','歡迎','SALE']
pat = r'(?!(?<=[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z])(?:{})(?<![A-Za-z](?=[A-Za-z]))'.format("|".join([re.escape(x) for x in v]))
print(re.findall(pat, s)) # =>  ['歡迎', 'SALE']
```

Comment: this   (?!(?<=[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z])   blew my mind. may be more explanation can help me to see why this is needed. But +1 for your awesome regex work.

Comment: @JBone Nested lookarounds are used here. I explained how they work in the answer. No idea what is unclear. Lookaheads always check the text immediately to the right of the current location, and lookbehinds always check the text immediately preceding (to the left of) the current location in string.

Comment: is that a positive look behind in a negative look ahead?

Comment: `(?!(?<=[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z])` is a negative lookahead with its own pattern, `(?<=[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z]`, that contains a positive lookbehind.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
 import re

 if (re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]',x[0]):
    print(x[0])
 else:
    x = x[1:]

 if(re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]',x[-1]):
    print(x[-1])
 else:
    x = x[:-1]
```

Comment: Thank you Pawanvir. Can we use `(?(?=regex)then|else)`?